# BottomNavigationBarItem label localization problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I use EasyLocalization to localize my app and it's working properly everywhere in my app except the BottomNavigationBar, it doesn't localize it properly and seems like it takes a step back.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
      onTap: onItemTap,
      currentIndex: currentIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Palette.color1,
      unselectedItemColor: Palette.color18,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Assets.icons.homeSvg.svg(color: iconColor(TeacherWallScreen)),
          label: tr(Translations.Menu_Home), // Doesn't update
        ),
      ],
    )
```